# How to fix probable error for Hindi language support?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to include Hindi language support on a Google Assistant action developed using the flash card template.
In line with the reference documentation, I have checked the Hindi language in the "Choose language(s) for your Actions" on the Action console.

I have also uploaded the content in a separate Google Sheet which is copied from the Flash Card template available. No changes made on it except for the content changes and the sheet name and Configuration Parameters sheet.

So far so good, but when I try to test it in the Simulator, the questions are not read out aloud. The answers are matched, hints and follow-ups are also read correctly, but it is only the question which is not read out aloud in the simulator. Hindi language Test is enabled on the Simulator.

I have tried re-adding the language and verified the format in the sheet. Other languages (English) works just fine.
I have also format-painted the question column with the format of other cells/columns which are correctly read on Simulator.

Here is the generated response JSON -

```
{
    "simpleResponse": {
        "ssml": "<speak>वाह! आप प्रोग्रामिंग लॅंग्वेज ट्रिविया में वापस लौट आए। आइए देखते हैं कि हम पिछली बातें फिर से याद कर पाते हैं या नहीं। <break time='750ms'/> यह रहा आपका पहला सवाल।</speak>"
     }
}
```

and here is the Audio tab output -

```
    <speak>
वाह! आप App में वापस लौट आए। आइए देखते हैं कि हम पिछली बातें फिर से याद कर पाते हैं या नहीं। <break time='750ms'/> यह रहा आपका पहला सवाल।
    </speak>
```

I expect the questions to also be read out correctly, but the actual result is silence on the Simulator. The content is well-enclosed in the request JSON, but not getting read out aloud.

Comment: I don't think SSML is designed to work with the templates. Does it work without SSML?

Comment: @NickFelker ssml works with templates. The English language support and even the answers and hints and follow-ups for the Hindi version worked. It's just the first question which is not read.